# Filter ng-repeat with dropdown without duplicating the dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

The same way, I can manually do `filter: { category : 'Popular'}` in `ng-repeat`, I'd like to be able to do the same thing with the dropdown.

I was able to make the basics work. I have two problems: I don't want the categories to duplicate themselves in the dropdown, I'd like to be able to see everything categorized "Popular" when I select "Popular" in the dropdown.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SuperCtrl" class="row">
  <ul class="small-12 medium-12 columns">
    <select ng-model="find" ng-options="entry.category for entry in parsedEntries"><option value="">Select Category</option></select>.
    <li ng-repeat="entry in parsedEntries | filter: find">
      <strong>{{ entry.title }} </strong><br>
      {{ entry.description }}
   </li>
 </ul></div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('SuperCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1lZWwacSVxTD_ciOsuNsrzeMTNAl0Dj8SOrbaMqPKM7U/od6/public/values?alt=json'
var parse = function(entry) {
  var category = entry['gsx$category']['$t'];
  var description = entry['gsx$description']['$t'];
  var title = entry['gsx$title']['$t'];
  return {
    category: category,
    description: description,
    title: title
  };
}
$http.get(url)
.success(function(response) {
  var entries = response['feed']['entry'];
  $scope.parsedEntries = [];
  for (key in entries) {
    var content = entries[key];
    $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));
  }
});
}]);
```

Comment: You use ng-repeat on both the option and li element inside the select tag. I think you could just remove the li tag and that way it wont be duplicated (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working as you want with :

```
<select ng-model="find" ng-options="entry.category as entry.category for entry in parsedEntries | unique: 'category'">
```

The `unique` filter is from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). It requires to add `'angular.filter'` you to your modules dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/zdemywk2/4/)**

NB: Not a problem by itself but I took the `<select>` element out of the `<ul>` one.

Comment: If I may ask one more thing: what's the best way to have the dropdown default to the first category item?

Comment: You can add a default value for the variable `find` in the controller. For example `$scope.find = 'popular';`. But I had to add `track by entry.category` in the ng-options attribute value after the unique filter, so that the default value appears selected. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/zdemywk2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put unique categories into in a string array called `categories`, sort the array, and display it with `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="find" ng-options="category as category for category in categories"><option value="">Select Category</option></select>.
```

Append this to your code after your parse function, and delete the `$http.get` you had. This defines a `contains` function and builds the array at the same time the objects come back:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === obj) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

$http.get(url)
.success(function(response) {
  var entries = response['feed']['entry'];
  $scope.parsedEntries = [];
  $scope.categories = [];
  for (key in entries) {
    var content = entries[key];
    var obj = parse(content);
    $scope.parsedEntries.push(obj);

    if (!contains($scope.categories, obj.category))
    {
      $scope.categories.push(obj.category);
    }
  }

  $scope.categories.sort();
})
```